# random a 512-bit integer N that is not a multiple of 2, 3, or 5

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

if you are to choose a random a 512-bit integer N that is not a multiple of 2, 3, or 5 What is the probability that N is prime?
i don't know the algorithm behind this one... i'm trying to work on a project but this is the starting point.. :)

Comment: Could this possibly be a homework assignment?

Comment: yes its is for a homework assignment.. but this is just the first step to get me going ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of primes less than n=2<sup>512</sup> is approximately n/log(n).  The number of numbers you are considering is 4/15*n, so the probability you are looking for is 15/(4*log(n)), which is about 1 %.

Comment: The other implied part of the reasoning here is that all of the primes in that range (except for the first three) are among the `4/15*n` numbers that you're considering - and 3 is of course much less than `2^512/log(2^512)`.

Answer (score 3):

**Probability bounds**

You may use [the following inequality for the prime pi function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIQc1.png):

[image]

(Where log is taken in base **e**)

So:

> 8.58774*10<sup>151</sup> < π(2<sup>512</sup>) < 8.93096*10<sup>151</sup>

And as you are only leaving alive 4/15 n numbers (because of killing he multiples of 2, 3 and 5), te probability is bounded by:

> 8.58774*10<sup>151</sup>/(4/15 2<sup>512</sup>) < P < 8.93096*10<sup>151</sup>/(4/15 2<sup>512</sup>)

Or:

### 0.010507 < P  < 0.010687

Which is a nice, pretty tight bound.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an exact answer or an approximation?  For an approximation you can use the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) or [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Comment: And for an exact answer you have to check them all. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds homeworkish so I suggest you generate some 512bit numbers and use some well known prime tests to get an approximate answer heuristically.

Comment: Even generating a 512-bit integer is non-trivial in some languages (you'd have to go to great lengths to do better than 64-bits in many cases).  Also the search space is quite large and the primes are fairly sparse in that neighborhood, so your "enumerate and test" heuristic is not likely to be very accurate.

Comment: "Even generating a 512-bit integer is non-trivial in some languages" - maybe best not to use any of those languages, then ;-)

Comment: @Michael: Generating a X-bit number is pretty easy in most languages and given the question it's probably in the realm of the OP's resources. Primes in that range are not that sparse! The prime number theorem says that the "average length" of the gap between a prime p and the next prime is ln p which is quite small for 512 bit numbers (else public key crypto would be too costly).

Comment: I guess it depends on what we mean by easy...my point was I think most languages do not have primitive data types that support ints that large.  As such it might require using byte arrays with bit-twiddling or something like java.math.BigInteger.  I would consider that non-trivial (although I guess maybe it's both non-trivial AND easy...we're both right :)  As for the accuracy, I'm aware of the prime number theorem but I might have spoken a bit too quickly...upon thinking about it for a bit, accuracy won't be that bad *if* you you generate a reasonable amount of samples.

Comment: @Michael: I tried this in Python, by the way, (`value = random.randint(1,2**512)`) and after discarding the banned multiples of 2,3,5 and doing a Miller-Rabin with 15 trials, I end up checking about 100 candidate primes per second on one core of my laptop. Not too shabby, although obviously the back-of-envelope solution using the prime number theorem is even faster :-) I think 15 rounds of MillerRabin is plenty, since we're not going to get all that accurate an estimate by this method in a reasonable time anyway.