# Probability of n-bit integers

Tags: math, integer, probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [random a 512-bit integer N that is not a multiple of 2, 3, or 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264605/random-a-512-bit-integer-n-that-is-not-a-multiple-of-2-3-or-5)

I have a question

for a random 512-bit integer n that isn't a multiple of 2,3, or 5 what is the chance that n is prime? what about that n is composite but fools the fermat primality test? what about that it is composite but doesn't fool the fermat primality test?

Comment: boy your professor is going to think you guys are pretty smart when you all get the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is definitely a homework problem, I'll point you at the [Prime Number Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), which should give you the probability that any large number is prime.

From there, modify the probability with your new information about composite numbers that have been eliminated (Hint: Think about how the problem space shrinks).

Best of luck!